# API changes? Animation add-on doesn't work since version 2.63

Tags: python, blender, add-on

My FlipAnimation add-on works fine until version 2.62 but refuses to work on newer versions. The main purpose of it is taking a range of keyframes of the currently active action and perform a `Copy Pose` and `Paste X-flipped Pose` on every relevant frame. So depending on the selected mode, either the whole action is mirrored or a specified range is processed and appended.

Now starting with 2.63 it 'pretends' to work but the pasted poses are not X-flipped. The code fragment which I guess is to blame for:

```
    for frame_item in self.keyframe_bone_dict.items ():
        frame = frame_item[0]
        bones = frame_item[1]
        context.scene.frame_set(frame)
        bpy.ops.pose.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        for bone_item in bones.items ():
            bone = bone_item[0]
            bpy.context.active_object.data.bones[bone].select = True
        bpy.ops.pose.copy()
        if self.append_mode:
            context.scene.frame_set(frame + self.append_frames_offset)
        bpy.ops.pose.paste(flipped=True)
```

`keyframe_bone_dict` contains for every frame to touch a dictionary of all affected bones. So I iterate over all keyframes, select the bones that have a keyframe defined here. Then copy the pose and do a paste X-flipped pose either at the current frame or at another frame that is append_frames_offset away. There are pasted keyframes at the right positions but their values are not X-flipped.

I studied the API changes at [Blender API changes](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_66_release/change_log.html#to-2-63) at  but did not find any suspect thing. Only some minor changes to KeyingSets like name => bl_label.

Is there anything else changed? Or what else could lead to the changed behaviour?

I just started to read about how to submit code to bf-extensions Trackers and then I ran into this issue while testing with different versions. Now I really stuck as I am new to add-on development.

Thanks a lot for your help

**UPDATE**

I did some further investigation and found out that after the paste pose operator returned successfully the follwing debug statement

```
print (context.active_pose_bone, " (after): ", context.active_pose_bone.rotation_quaternion)
```

showed reasonable i.e. correct values for the considered bone's keyframe. But after the add-on has finished, the same keys are either unchanged or have neglegible changes in their quaternion members (0 - 1%). Sometimes the affected bone has changed slightly. Really strange :-(

**UPDATE 2**
The add-on runs is designed to run in pose mode only and the panel is hidden in any other mode. Before starting the copy and pasting process, a bunch of statements is executed to ensure that all preconditions are met. This includes: Does the active object contain an armature with at least one action defined, is there an action selected, is *Automatic Keyframe Insertion Using Active Keying Set Only* and *Automatic Keyframe Insertion Using Active Keying Set Only* enabled.

More info:

- [Video about how it worked before and should do again](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GChWp0W5lnA)
- [Code at GitHub](https://github.com/kayy/FlipAnimation), feel free to fork the project
- [Blog entry](http://www.scio.de/en/blog-a-news/scio-development-blog-en/entry/flip-animation-add-on-for-mirroring-keyframes-in-blender)

Comment: If you haven't already, ask on the #blenderpython IRC channel on freenode.org. Sounds like a mode issue which results in nothing updating but if it worked on 2.62 it should be the same.

Comment: @neomonkeus thanks, I will give it try when SO and the cross posting at blender.org don't get hints. 'Mode issue'? Sounds like you have run into similar problems in the past?

Comment: Currently porting a 2.4x script. Another developer is working on armature import/export and if your not in the correct mode, updates might not occur. But again this is just a general observation so would be surprised if it was the cause of the issue.

Comment: @neomonkeus I updated the question, the add-on runs only when in pose mode.

Comment: @Kay Have you solved this? I run into the same today.

Comment: @stacker No I still keep an old version to use the plugin

Comment: @Kay you might be interested in http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6870/how-can-the-active-bone-group-be-set-from-a-script

Comment: @stacker thanks, I just added it to favourites and will try it out